# Reference ul lists in array and toggle their visibility

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, pagination, navigation

I've created a small archive layout with links where I need to add some form of pagination. I don't want to reload the page so I went for a JS navigation instead where I load all links at once, then show / hide 10 at a time by prev / next buttons. Each 10 items gets their own list container (ul).

JS,

```
   if ($('.archive').length > 0) {
        var lists = [],
            traverse = 0;
        $('.archive ul').each(function() {
          lists.push($(this));
        });
      }
      $('.previous').click(function(e) {
        traverse--;
        if (traverse === 0) {
          $(this).addClass('inactive');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $('.next').click(function(e) {
        traverse++;
        if (traverse === lists.length) {
          $(this).addClass('inactive');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
```

HTML,

```
<div class="archive">
    <ul>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
        <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"></a>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

CSS,

```
    ul:not(:first-of-type) {
        display: none;
    }
```

This works for the actual navigation, but I'm unsure as how to reference each list in order to hide / display them. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your HTML too

Comment: I have a jquery plugin that would work for this here is the link.  It is not open source but if you purchase it I will help you implement or customize what you need.  Here is a link to a preview   http://codecanyon.net/item/paginate-page-building-framework/full_screen_preview/7828380

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to solve it. Will post my code as an answer in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. In the JS, add the following

```
  if ($('.archive ul').length > 1) {
    $('.previous, .next').css('display', 'inline-block');
    var lists = [];
        i = 0;
    $('.archive ul').each(function() {
      lists.push($(this));
    });
  }
  $('.previous').click(function(e) {
    i--;
    $('.archive ul:visible').fadeOut(function() {
      lists[i].fadeIn(200);
    });
    if (i < lists.length) {
      $('.next').removeClass('inactive');
    }
    if (i === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.next').click(function(e) {
    i++;
    $('.archive ul:visible').fadeOut(function() {
      lists[i].fadeIn(200);
    });
    if (i > 0) {
      $('.previous').removeClass('inactive');
    }
    if (i === lists.length - 1) {
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

I added an additional checker to see if there is more than one list, and in that case hide / show the nav.